# What about if you work with alcohol but don't drink it?, is that samething?

Tags: salat, sawm, alcohol

I heard if you drink alcohol, your salah wouldn't be accepted for 40 days, what about if you work with alcohol but don't drink it?, is that samething?.  Another way of asking above question, is working with alcohol effects your salah and fasting? Please provide evidence when answering the question.

Comment: What kind of work?

Comment: @Crimson like working for a restaurant or shop, where you sell or serve alcohol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graded sahih and narrated by Abdullah ibn Umar the following Hadith states:

> يَقُولُ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ لَعَنَ اللَّهُ الْخَمْرَ وَشَارِبَهَا وَسَاقِيَهَا وَبَائِعَهَا وَمُبْتَاعَهَا وَعَاصِرَهَا وَمُعْتَصِرَهَا وَحَامِلَهَا وَالْمَحْمُولَةَ إِلَيْهِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Allah has *cursed wine, its drinker, its server, its seller, its buyer, its presser, the one for whom it is pressed, the one who conveys it, and the one to whom it is conveyed.*
>
> <sub>[Sunan Abu Dawud 3674](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/6)</sub>

Allah has mentioned in the Quran that alcohol is forbidden for us. You should not be involved in anything with alcohol.

Regarding fasting and salah, they will still be valid but you may not get the reward you could get as you are still committing a sin<sup>[See this](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/150759/performing-prayers-while-persisting-in-committing-some-sins)</sup>. Your prayers not being accepted for 40 days does not mean they are not valid. See [Does drinking alcohol led to forty days of impuriy in which no prayer is accepted?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28626/does-drinking-alcohol-led-to-forty-days-of-impuriy-in-which-no-prayer-is-accepte).